# What did Ivan Illich think of Helmut Schoeck?

Tags: political-philosophy, ivan-illich

Is there any record of Ivan Illich commenting on the writings, viewpoints or life of Helmut Schoeck?

Comment: I wonder if you could provide more context for the question. What about Helmut Schoeck makes you want to associate Illich with him? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmut_Schoeck

Answer (score 1):

I searched the following books by Ivan Illich on the Internet Archive using "Helmut" and "Schoeck" in separate searches without finding reference made to Helmut Schoeck:

- [Deschooling Society](https://archive.org/details/ERIC_ED532618)
- [Medical Nemesis](https://archive.org/details/MedicalNemesis)
- [In the Mirror of the Past: Lectures and Addresses 1978 - 1990](https://archive.org/details/inmirrorofpast00illi)

The third book was selected to get a representation of his views after two of his more popular books.

That he could not be found referenced in these books does not mean he did not have an opinion on Helmut Schoeck, but it does suggest that he might not have had one.

Wikipedia describes Schoeck's views as follows:

> A polemicist against the New Left movements of the 1960s, Schoeck criticized their ideas from a conservative-liberal viewpoint. The egalitarian and anti-capitalist mentality of the leftish generation was the particular target of Schoeck's attacks.

Wikipedia has this to say about Illich:

> While Illich never referred to himself as an anarchist in print, he was closely associated with major figures in left-anarchist circles, notably Paul Goodman and unschooling advocate John Holt. Goodman is credited in Deschooling Society with having "radically obliged" Illich to revise his thinking...

Based on these descriptions it does not appear that Illich and Schoeck would have agreed with each other. Furthermore, Schoeck may not have been relevant to the arguments Illich was trying to present about modern institutions.

---

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, March 6). Helmut Schoeck. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 18:37, June 23, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Helmut_Schoeck&oldid=886547262

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, April 1). Ivan Illich. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 18:36, June 23, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ivan_Illich&oldid=890533963